# My download speed is terrible

Tags: internet, ethernet, internet-speed

When I try downloading a game my download speed is 1 mb/s. When I restart my router or pc the speed jumps to 5 mb/s but quickly get back down. When in task manager it shows the game is using 10 mb/s ,which is also only 1 percent of my network.I am using an ethernet cable. My download speed was once over 13 mb/s. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try TCP./IP Reset, restart and test.   Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
(1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
(2) ipconfig /flushdns
(3) restart the computer
(b) update the network driver and test, and then (c) reinstall the operating system.

Comment: Download speeds are a combination of many things. Not just the internet speed you have, but also the upload speed on the server. Many times, the internet download speed is way higher than the upload speed of the server, and slow downloads are expected. This highly depends on many things. Large game companies tend to assign extra bandwidth to modern games as there is large demand for those, and lower bandwidth for older games. Also new games will have many concurrent downloads at the same time when it is a few days old, which means the server just can't handle that many downloads.

Comment: Those are seriously slow speeds. Can you confirm that you are still getting these speeds when using a CAT5e or CAT6 cable connected directly to your router without any interconnecting equipment (switches, routers, extenders) sitting in-between? Do not use a CAT5 cable because they are 10 times slower than CAT5e and CAT6.

Comment: Make sure you’re not confusing Megabytes and Megabits. // What’s your internet plan’s rated speed? What kind of connection is it, DSL, cable, fibre, …?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, the internet speed is slow only *while you are playing a game*. It would seem the PC itself does not have the power to both run a game and download rapidly. The limiting factor might be CPU usage, I/O issues, or something else.